# Bootstrap collapse accordion collapses instantly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using bootstrap collapse to create an accordion list. The code, as far as I am concerned is correct since it works on any online editor I have tried so far.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calinp/eok1ntbx/)

```
<div id="menu" style="max-width: 600px;">
<div class="panel list-group">
<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s1" data-parent="#menu" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 1.5px;">
  <span class="well well-sm bs-accordion-left-number">1</span><span class="bs-accordion-title">Test 1</span><span class="pull-right">10</span></a>
<div id="s1" class="sublinks collapse">
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test2</a>
</div>
<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s2" data-parent="#menu" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 1.5px;">
  <span class="well well-sm bs-accordion-left-number">2</span><span class="bs-accordion-title">Test 2</span><span class="pull-right">10</span></a>
<div id="s2" class="sublinks collapse">
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test2</a>
</div>
<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s3" data-parent="#menu" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 1.5px;">
  <span class="well well-sm bs-accordion-left-number">3</span><span class="bs-accordion-title">Test 3</span><span class="pull-right">10</span></a>
<div id="s3" class="sublinks collapse">
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test2</a>
</div>
<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s4" data-parent="#menu" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 1.5px;">
  <span class="well well-sm bs-accordion-left-number">4</span><span class="bs-accordion-title">Test 4</span><span class="pull-right">10</span></a>
<div id="s4" class="sublinks collapse">
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test2</a>
</div>
<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s5" data-parent="#menu" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 1.5px;">
  <span class="well well-sm bs-accordion-left-number">5</span><span class="bs-accordion-title">Test 5</span><span class="pull-right">10</span></a>
<div id="s5" class="sublinks collapse">
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test2</a>
</div>
<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s6" data-parent="#menu" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 1.5px;">
  <span class="well well-sm bs-accordion-left-number">6</span><span class="bs-accordion-title">Test 6</span><span class="pull-right">10</span></a>
<div id="s6" class="sublinks collapse">
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> test2</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the accordion closes (height decreases) it closes instantly, while when it opens (height increases) it follows the transition properties (like it should). I am aware that the problem lies somewhere withing my website (on which I am using a CMS with a custom template with loads of custom styling which may interfere. I would like someone to point me in the right direction to find where this bug happens.

Here are some screenshots using Chrome's Inspect Element Tool on both Online Editor and Personal Website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMHfZ.jpg

Comment: The .sublinks class appears to be applying JS to the same element.

Comment: I have tried without using the .sublinks class and the same thing happens.  I have reviewed the images I posted and apparently I did it the other way around for both cases, switched accordion closed with accordion opened. I am just editing and reuploading the images. The problem seems to be that the .collapse class is still being used when the accordion is opened, as opposed to the online editor where it just uses an "in" class.